# Open texture from fragment shader

Tags: glsl, glsles

I'm trying to write a shader for Minecraft bedrock edition, and since I don't have access to the code of the game, just the GLSLes shaders, I was wondering if there was any way for me to access a texture from the fragment shader without having to pass it through the c++ code.

Comment: Your question is unclear. What to you mean by *"without having to pass it throught the c++ code"*. The texture needs to be loaded onto the GPU. The texture object needs to be bound to a texture unit. The biding between the texture object and the texture sampler uniform can be done in-shader with [Binding Point Layout Qualifiers](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Layout_Qualifier_(GLSL)#Binding_points). However you have to know the texture unit.

Comment: I mean to have the code loading the texture entirely in the shader and not in the main code. If I understand correclty, you're saying that it's impossible?

Comment: *"I mean to have the code loading the texture entirely in the shader [...]"* - Sorry, this is impossible. The shader code runs on the GPU and has no direct access to CPU resources.

Comment: No, there's no practical way to do this. But what you could do is find an existing texture in Minecraft that you have access to in the shader and can control (e.g. the block textures) and change it to contain what you need?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is as stated in the comments above : there's no way. GLSL doesn't work this way.